# Deploying multiple versions of Red Hat Developer Toolset to multiple RHEL version

Tags: redhat, rhel, rhel7, redhat-dts

Can I deploy multiple versions of Red Hat Developer Toolset  to multiple versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Toolset (DTS) installs itself in different parts of the file system, so 'yes' you can install multiple versions of DTS on RHEL.  Both RHEL 6 and 7 are supported today.